# How to calculate time complexity of big-theta in fragments of code?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm doing exercise on analyzing time complexity on fragments of code, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how the following two code can have different time complexity:

```
for(a=1,a<=n,a++):
 for(b=1,b<=a, b++):
   c=c+1
```

Which the running time of the code can
 be expressed as θ(n^2).

Yet,

```
for(a=1,a<=n,a=2*a):
 for(b=1,b<=a, b++):
   c=c+1
```

is expressed as θ(n).

I thought the second fragments of code has the running time of θ(n^2/2)=θ(n^2).
Apparently I was mistaken.
Could some please give some hints of how to properly analyzed the time complexity of the mentioned two codes?
It would help a lot, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you thought the second code fragment was `θ(n^2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You will see it clearly when unfolding those. Let me try:

First fragment: suppose n = 8

```
a = 1, b = 1
a = 2, b = 1,2
a = 3, b = 1,2,3
a = 4, b = 1,2,3,4
a = 5, b = 1,2,3,4,5
a = 6, b = 1,2,3,4,5,6
a = 7, b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
a = 8, b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Second fragment: suppose n = 8

```
a = 1, b = 1
a = 2, b = 1,2
a = 4, b = 1,2,3,4
a = 8, b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

By simply counting the number of loops above, you will start to see that `a=a*2` has canceled the number of outer loop by the same proportion.

Actually, I believe the answer should be `θ(n log(n))`

Hope this help.

Comment: Are you sure about `n log n`? Can you provide a more rigorous proof of this assertion?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog actually no. i'm not sure. but I'll try to sketch the proof when free. or if you have opinion feel free to comment.